# Properties file reset when modifying or adding value

Tags: java, xml, properties-file

What I need is a simple way to read and write certain values to a XML file? I want it to be simple something like this:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setValue("WIDTH", 1000);
int WIDTH = config.getValue("WIDTH");
```

It needs to be writable and readable at all times. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Configuration {
    Properties config;

    public Configuration() {
        config = new Properties();
    }

    public void setValue(String name, String value) {
        try {
            config.setProperty(name, value);
            config.storeToXML(new FileOutputStream("MyXmlConfig.xml"), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getValue(String name) {
        try {
            config.loadFromXML(new FileInputStream("MyXmlConfig.xml"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return config.getProperty(name);
    }
}
```

The problem with what I have is that it resets the created file when a variable is updated or added.

Comment: An INI file could fit more well.

Comment: Well, it's a good file format for simple configs. XML works too.

Comment: I would use JSON for this implementation.

Comment: INI could also work but I have chosen XML. There is no reason behind it other then it looks well formatted.

Comment: @demostene, The format doesn't really matter as long as it works.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in class `java.util.Properties` supports this use case:

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.loadFromXML(new FileInputStream("c:/MyXmlConfig.xml"));
config.setProperty("WIDTH", "1000");
int WIDTH = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("WIDTH"));
config.storeToXML(new FileOutputStream("c:/MyXmlConfig.xml"), "My config file");
```

Comment: It works! Kinda..... I need to be able to update a variables value. This (meaning the way I have set it out) resets the file.